# Get interval seconds between two datetime in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

2009-10-05 18:11:08

2009-10-05 18:07:13

This should generate 235,how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate total seconds in PHP DateInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) to do that:

```
$diff = strtotime('2009-10-05 18:11:08') - strtotime('2009-10-05 18:07:13')
```

A similar approach is possible with DateTime objects, e.g.

```
$date = new DateTime( '2009-10-05 18:07:13' );
$date2 = new DateTime( '2009-10-05 18:11:08' );

$diff = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Note: Be sure you use capital "H" for hours (24h mode) when your "lower" time is "now" and you use `date()` to get datetime of now ( `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` ).

Comment: ```
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.
```

Comment: check JCM answer and choose your case

Answer (score 188):

With DateTime objects, you can do it like this:

```
$date = new DateTime( '2009-10-05 18:07:13' );
$date2 = new DateTime( '2009-10-05 18:11:08' );

$diffInSeconds = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: This also takes daylight savings time into account!

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to the question. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that, in order for daylight savings to be taken into account correctly, you need to provide the correct DateTimeZone. If your system is set up correctly then php might already know your timezone from the system default. If in question, manually instanciate one like so: $tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'); and pass it to the DateTime constructor as second parameter.

Comment: great solution but for longer periods (example 1 hour) I receive negative value (overflow?), any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

PHP Date Time reference is helpful for things like this: [PHP Date Time Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

[strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) is probably the best way.

```
$seconds = strtotime('2009-10-05 18:11:08') - strtotime('2009-10-05 18:07:13')
```

Answer (score 10):

For those worrying about the limitations of using timestamps (i.e. using dates before 1970 and beyond 2038), you can simply calculate the difference in seconds like so:

```
$start = new DateTime('2009-10-05 18:07:13');
$end = new DateTime('2009-10-05 18:11:08');
$diff = $start->diff($end);

$daysInSecs = $diff->format('%r%a') * 24 * 60 * 60;
$hoursInSecs = $diff->h * 60 * 60;
$minsInSecs = $diff->i * 60;

$seconds = $daysInSecs + $hoursInSecs + $minsInSecs + $diff->s;

echo $seconds; // output: 235
```

Wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-get-the-datetime-difference-in-seconds-between-two-datetime-objects-in-php) for those interested in reading more.

Comment: IMO it's a good way to calculate the seconds as leap year gets messed up in PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64908868/2190689. From `2024-02-24 00:00:00` to `2024-03-24 00:00:00` It's 29 days. But according to DateInterval, it's 1 month which changes the second calculation.

Answer (score 6):

Because of unix epoch limitations, you could have problems compairing dates before 1970 and after 2038. I choose to loose precision (=don't look at the single second) but avoid to pass trough unix epoch conversions (getTimestamp). It depends on what you are doing to do...

In my case, using 365 instead (12*30) and "30" as mean month lenght, reduced the error in an usable output.

```
function DateIntervalToSec($start,$end){ // as datetime object returns difference in seconds
    $diff = $end->diff($start);
    $diff_sec = $diff->format('%r').( // prepend the sign - if negative, change it to R if you want the +, too
                ($diff->s)+ // seconds (no errors)
                (60*($diff->i))+ // minutes (no errors)
                (60*60*($diff->h))+ // hours (no errors)
                (24*60*60*($diff->d))+ // days (no errors)
                (30*24*60*60*($diff->m))+ // months (???)
                (365*24*60*60*($diff->y)) // years (???)
                );
    return $diff_sec;
}
```

Note that the error could be 0, if "mean" quantities are intended for diff. The PHP docs don't speaks about this...
In a bad case, error could be:

- 0 seconds if diff is applied to time gaps < 1 month
- 0 to 3 days if diff is applied to time gaps > 1 month
- 0 to 14 days if diff is applied to time gaps > 1 year

I prefer to suppose that somebody decided to consider "m" as 30 days and "y" as 365, charging "d" with the difference when "diff" walk trough non-30-days months...

If somebody knows something more about this and can provide official documentation, is welcome!

Comment: Use the days property instead of the d property to get the exact days in between the two days. So no inaccurate results there.

Answer (score 3):

```
strtotime("2009-10-05 18:11:08") - strtotime("2009-10-05 18:07:13")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @designcise is wrong when "end date" is before "start date".
Here is the corrected calculation

```
$diff = $start->diff($end);

$daysInSecs = $diff->format('%r%a') * 24 * 60 * 60;
$hoursInSecs = $diff->format('%r%h') * 60 * 60;
$minsInSecs = $diff->format('%r%i') * 60;

$seconds = $daysInSecs + $hoursInSecs + $minsInSecs + $diff->format('%r%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem and came up with this solution that should work for almost any date, including those before 1970 or after 2038:

```
$loDate = new DateTime('1000-01-01');
$hiDate = new DateTime('2525-01-01');

if ($hiDate >= $loDate) {
    $diff = $loDate->diff($hiDate);
    $seconds = bcmul((string) $diff->days, '86400');

    if ($diff->h > 0 || $diff->i > 0 || $diff->s > 0) {
        $seconds = bcadd($seconds, (string) ($diff->h * 3600));
        $seconds = bcadd($seconds, (string) ($diff->i * 60));
        $seconds = bcadd($seconds, (string) $diff->s);
    }
 }
```

The `DateTime` class is not smart enough to account for calendar changes made in [1752](https://libguides.ctstatelibrary.org/hg/colonialresearch/calendar) (when Sept 2, 1752 was followed by Sept 14, 1752), so don't count on this to handle historical dates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2009-10-05 18:11:08');
$date2 = new DateTime('2009-10-05 18:07:13');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->s + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->h * 3600 + $interval->days * 86400;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

A simple and exact solution (exemplifying Nilz11's comment):

```
$hiDate = new DateTime("2310-05-22 08:33:26");
$loDate = new DateTime("1910-11-03 13:00:01");
$diff = $hiDate->diff($loDate);
$secs = ((($diff->format("%a") * 24) + $diff->format("%H")) * 60 + 
   $diff->format("%i")) * 60 + $diff->format("%s");
```