# Calculate total seconds in PHP DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime, date

What is the best way to calculate the total number of seconds between two dates?  So far, I've tried something along the lines of:

```
$delta   = $date->diff(new DateTime('now'));
$seconds = $delta->days * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

However, the `days` property of the DateInterval object seems to be broken in the current PHP5.3 build (at least on Windows, it always returns the same `6015` value).  I also attempted to do it in a way which would fail to preserve number of days in each month (rounds to 30), leap years, etc:

```
$seconds = ($delta->s)
         + ($delta->i * 60)
         + ($delta->h * 60 * 60)
         + ($delta->d * 60 * 60 * 24)
         + ($delta->m * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
         + ($delta->y * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

But I'm really not happy with using this half-assed solution.

Comment: What is the result of `$delta->format("%r%s")` ?

Comment: @warrenm The problem with `format` is when say the number of seconds is 0 while the number of minutes is 1, `$delta->format("%r%s")` turns out to be 0 :(

Comment: Worse yet, speaking as somebody now fixing a defect caught in code review from a coder who pasted your EXACT code above -- not every month has 30 days, and not every year has 365 days. :) [Edit: and that coder may have been myself!]

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Could you not compare the [time stamps](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) instead?

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$diff = $date->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp()
```

Comment: I think this works without lurking edge cases (wouldn't bet my life on it though having just spent 10 months doing a DateTime refactor of a large PHP app) but it should be noted that it's a workaround that doesn't solve the comparing-DateIntervals problem. It'd still be really nice to have that ability.

Comment: If you're stuck with PHP 5.2 on your crappy shared hoster, use `format('U')` instead of `getTimestamp()`.

Comment: Your solution is not compatible w/ year 2038 bug

Comment: @JackM. Good to know. I do hope whatever is being built now isn't running anymore in 2037. Feel free to provide a year 2038 bug safe alternative solution.

Comment: @JackM. Is it compatible with year 2038 on 64-bit systems? If so, will 32-bit PHP remain supported in 2038?

Answer (score 50):

This function allows you to get the total duration in seconds from a DateInterval object

```
/**
 * @param DateInterval $dateInterval
 * @return int seconds
 */
function dateIntervalToSeconds($dateInterval)
{
    $reference = new DateTimeImmutable;
    $endTime = $reference->add($dateInterval);

    return $endTime->getTimestamp() - $reference->getTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that DateTimeImmutable is only available from PHP 5.5 or higher.

Comment: I think you have to replace the return variables `$endTime` and `$reference` with each other, since this gives me a minus result with a future interval datetime value.

Comment: I don't think Timestamp is in Seconds either.   PHP DateTime = Horrific API

Answer (score 9):

`DateTime::diff` returns a `DateInterval` object between 2 dates.

The `DateInterval` object gives all the informations (the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds).

Here's a sample code:

```
/**
 * intervalToSeconds
 *
 * @param  DateInterval $interval
 * @return int
 */
function intervalToSeconds(\DateInterval $interval) {
    return $interval->days * 86400 + $interval->h * 3600 + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->s;
}

$date_1 = new \DateTime('2021-03-03 05:59:19');
$date_2 = new \DateTime('now');
$interval = $date_1->diff($date_2);
echo intervalToSeconds($interval);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```
$currentTime = time();
$timeInPast = strtotime("2009-01-01 00:00:00");

$differenceInSeconds = $currentTime - $timeInPast;
```

time() returns the current time in seconds since the epoch time (1970-01-01T00:00:00), and strtotime does the same, but based on a specific date/time you give.

Answer (score 5):

```
static function getIntervalUnits($interval, $unit)
{
    // Day
    $total = $interval->format('%a');
    if ($unit == TimeZoneCalc::Days)
        return $total;
    //hour
    $total = ($total * 24) + ($interval->h );
    if ($unit == TimeZoneCalc::Hours)
        return $total;
    //min
    $total = ($total * 60) + ($interval->i );
    if ($unit == TimeZoneCalc::Minutes)
        return $total;  
    //sec
    $total = ($total * 60) + ($interval->s );
    if ($unit == TimeZoneCalc::Seconds)
        return $total;  

    return false;
}
```