# PHP Parsing Amazon EC2 instance 'launchTime'

Tags: php, parsing, amazon-ec2

When you describe your EC2 instances, you get an XML node of:-

```
[launchTime] => 2011-10-14T09:22:37.000Z
```

I'd like to use this command with PHP, to measure the number of seconds the instance has been on and take actions.

It seems to me there's a number of ways to break this down, including explodes and string searches and regex. But, what is the *best* way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINAL ANSWER:

Okay, after checking out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval), I've decided on this approach as the only one that seems to return an accurate measure:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $date);
$now = new DateTime();
echo ($now->getTimestamp() - $dt->getTimestamp())."\n";
```

ATTEMPTS:

In PHP 5.3 using classes (no 'U' format):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $arr['launchTime']);
echo (new DateTime())->format('U');
```

In PHP 5.3 using procedural calls (also works like final solution):

```
$dt = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $arr['launchTime']);
$now = date_create();
echo ($now->getTimestamp() - $dt->getTimestamp());
```

In any version using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (return wrong time):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo time() - strtotime($arr['launchTime']);
```

Comment: hm, I just noticed that 'U' doesn't seem to work with DateInterval (works with all the other date formats); annoying... back to the drawing tablet...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure strtotime is returning an accurate measure; it doesn't seem to do leap years and daylight savings accurately, [according to this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: You're right, it's currently BST (+1 hours from GMT) and using the above means I have to manually add 1 hour to it currently. Apart from that, and also that I'm pretty sure constructor dereferencing is a PHP 5.4 feature (not 5.3), all good!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ts = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s?????', '2011-10-14T09:22:37.000Z');
echo $ts->diff(new DateTime())->format('U');
```

assuming you're on PHP 5.3+

Comment: Thanks Marc, looks nice and simple. I have 5.3.8, yet this says "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Date' not found"?

Comment: Thanks again, Marc. Unfortunately, I still get nothing out of this. I'd love to offer some more insight to that, but basically all I see is a non-object for diff, so that's the first sign of it not working. Have you got it working?

Comment: Hmm. appears that the `.000Z` at the end of the string is making the DateTime parser b0rk, so it's returning false.

Comment: or `?????` works too, except that's five digits and microseconds can vary from 2-6, I think ;)

Comment: shame that U doesn't work; can use it with all the other DateTime classes and formats :(