# Evaluating DateTime::diff Objects in a Procedural Manner

Tags: php, datetime

I have a countdown function that (in part) returns the "time left" until a given date/time.  The value is returned as a DateInterval object and is calculated using the diff method.

```
//calculate countdown time
$time_diff = $countdown->diff($current);
```

Given that $time_diff is a DateInterval object, how would I do this?

```
if ($time_diff > 60) {

    //do stuff

}
```

I know the code above doesn't work, but how can/should I evaluate the equivalent condition ("more than 60 sec left in this DateInterval object")?

The problem is that the script *used* to return the "time left" as a Unix timestamp integer, and the function is utilized in a more procedural manner by a wide array of scripts in my system.

Thank you in advance for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: Is $time_diff really a DateTime object, or is it a DateInterval object as would be more appropriate

Comment: Sorry - you are correct: it is a DateInterval object rather than a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not possible to use the format() method on a DateInterval object to get directly the *total* amount of remaining time in seconds, I ended up adding a helper in my function to return the "time left" as a Unix timestamp along with the DateInterval object.

```
//calculate unix timetamps
$current_ts = time();
$countdown_ts = $countdown->getTimestamp();
$timestamp_diff = ($current_ts < $countdown_ts) ? ($countdown_ts - $current_ts) : 0;
```

Hope this is useful to others.

PS.  Stackoverflow is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the individual values off the object:

```
if ($time_diff->s > 60) {

    //do stuff

}
```

See the [DateInterval class structure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for a full list of properties. However i think you need to look at each value on the object (days, minutes, years, etc.) and add them all up if you want the TOTAL seconds elapsed - ofcourse in your use case (a countdown timer) it may never be difference of more than seconds so that might not be necessary.

Comment: In this scenario, the time diff could be several months.  So I would need to get the total time remaining in seconds, rather than the individual value of seconds in the DateInterval object.  This would be one way:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval), but in that case I'd probably just convert back to a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Use [format()](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.format.php).

```
echo $time_diff->format('%R%a days'); //'days' here, you need to change as you want
```

See also [diff](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: But is it possible to use the format() method to get the total amount of time remaining in seconds?

Comment: Not directly, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php