# Converting a Total Time to Seconds

Tags: php, datetime

I'm totalling up time like so.

```
$totalTimeDiff = new DateTime("@0");
foreach($dbrecords as $row)
{
    $timeDiff = date_diff( ... two datetimes from my database ... )
    $totalTimeDiff->add($timeDiff);
}
```

So `$totalTimeDiff` is a DateTime object with the sum of all of the time differences added together (so a sum of all of the durations). How can I get the total time in seconds?

Comment: 1. use `DateInterval`, as you are calculating a proper interval and not storing a date; 2. read its documentation in order to get your interval in seconds.

Comment: If I use date_diff to get a difference, how can I convert that to seconds? I didn't see that in the documentation. I just see how to retrieve the seconds from there.

Comment: [Just compute the difference with _now_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval).

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple?

```
$totalseconds=0;
foreach($dbrecords as $row)
  $totalseconds+=(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(second_datetime)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(first_datetime));
```

Comment: This will work as long as the values in the database are saved with respect to UTC.  If storing local values (hopefully not), then you have to take time zones and DST into account, which is much more difficult.

Comment: Since we calculate the difference, the time offset will delta out as long as both have the same.

Comment: True, but they might not necessarily be the same if one value is before a transition and the other is after.

Comment: If this is the case, then a lot of things will break: End time might be before start time

Comment: In addition to that, the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function will rebase to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

use strtotime function

echo strtotime('01:00:00') - strtotime('TODAY');

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalTimeDiff->format('U');
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking moonwave99's advice, I used DateInterval (can't remember why I went with DateTime for that in the first place, possibly a workaround for something at another stage of the project) and computed the seconds by adding each value to the total after converting it to seconds (converting hours and minutes to seconds and summing them up). I did this by using the [DateInterval class's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) seconds property as well as the following function to convert a DateInterval to seconds (Note: only accounted for days, hours, minutes, and seconds for my specific case as there's no chance the amount will exceed one month):

```
function convertDateIntervalToSeconds($dateInterval)
{
    $days = $dateInterval->d * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $hours = $dateInterval->h * 60 * 60;
    $minutes = $dateInterval->i * 60;
    $seconds = $dateInterval->s;

    return $hours + $minutes + $seconds;
}
```