# I want to find the percentage of completion from two dates?

Tags: php, date, time

im using PHP

I don't know if this is possible but i have a start date and and end date, im wanting to get the percentage of completed time from these two dates.

so if it will need to take the start end and current time and date and fire back

35% Completed etc..

Nov 02nd 2015 14:05:15
Nov 02nd 2015 18:05:15

Thanks any tips or guide is a big help.

I have been trying to use this but its not working.

```
<?php

$startDate = date_create('$start');
$endDate = date_create('$end');
$currentDate = date_create('$date');

$totalTime = date_diff($endDate, $startDate); 
$elapsedTime = date_diff($currentDate, $startDate);

$totalTimeDays = $totalTime->format("%d");
$elapsedTimeDays = $elapsedTime->format("%d");

echo "Total project time = " . $totalTimeDays . "<br/>";
echo "Elapsed project time = " . $elapsedTimeDays  . "<br/>";
echo "Percent of project complete = " . ($elapsedTimeDays / $totalTimeDays) * 100.0;

?>
```

Comment: What does $elapsedTimeDays and $totalTimeDays output as in your script above?

Comment: What do you mean nothing loans? As in it's a white page? If so, what's the error given?

Comment: $date = gmdate('M dS Y H:i:s');
$start = "Nov 02nd 2015 14:05:15";
$end = "Nov 02nd 2015 18:05:15";

Comment: sure its because of the dates

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your quotes on the first 3 lines

```
$startDate = date_create($start);
$endDate = date_create($end);
$currentDate = date_create($date);
```

And the format you use is wrong  => use the **%a** which count all days

--EDIT WITH COMPLETE EXAMPLE--

```
<?php
// Note that i prefer the use of true object notation
$start = '2010-01-01';
$end = '2010-10-01';
$date = '2010-05-01';

$startDate = new DateTime($start);
$endDate = new DateTime($end);
$currentDate = new DateTime($date);

$totalTime = $endDate->diff($startDate); 
$elapsedTime = $currentDate->diff($startDate);

$totalTimeDays = $totalTime->format('%a'); // the change is here
$elapsedTimeDays = $elapsedTime->format('%a');  // the change is here
//var_dump($totalTime, $elapsedTime);

echo "Total project time = " . $totalTimeDays . "<br/>";
echo "Elapsed project time = " . $elapsedTimeDays  . "<br/>";
echo "Percent of project complete = " . ($elapsedTimeDays / $totalTimeDays) * 100.0;

?>
```

-- EDIT 2---
Your 500 error is a PHP division by 0 error as the $elapsedTime->format('%a'); returns 0 (or NULL)

-- EDIT 3 --

```
$start = '2015-11-02 14:05:15';
$end = '2015-11-02 18:05:15';
$date = '2015-11-02 16:12:15';

$startDate = new DateTime($start);
$endDate = new DateTime($end);
$currentDate = new DateTime($date);


$totalTime = $endDate->getTimestamp() - $startDate->getTimestamp();
$elapsedTime = $currentDate->getTimestamp() - $startDate->getTimestamp();

echo "Total project time = " . $totalTime . "<br/>";
echo "Elapsed project time = " . $elapsedTime  . "<br/>";
echo "Percent of project complete = " . ($elapsedTime / $totalTime) * 100.0;
```

Comment: You tried the full example ? What dates are you using ? Have you access to you php error log ?

Comment: Im using these dates, i can change them but i need to include the time. Nov 02nd 2015 14:05:15 -- Nov 02nd 2015 18:05:15

Comment: Ok, so you need to display a diff between two dates separated by a few hours. you should use another method as DateInterval is not for this accuracy.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this helps

Comment: Please, give me the values of your 3 dates dans the php erro you encounter ;)

Comment: Line 11-Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimestamp() i

Comment: Check that you have the correct PHP version, and the package installed. You should also test whith http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timestamp-get.php

Comment: I looked into that and added the correct syntax and it just displays 0 on all three, closer

Comment: PLease, update your question with your last code and error