# How to use date difference as an integer in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have found various methods to calculate the number of dates between 2 dates by first using `date_create()` and passing it the dates (without time) and then using `->diff` on one of the them and works perfectly fine.

However when I attempt to do some integer related operations on it, such as comparing it if difference is >0 then it shows an error :

> Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to integer

I have used var_dump() and it shows the value in it stores as string, but `intval()` is also not successful over it. Any other way to change it to integer?

Code is as follows:

```
$d1 = date_create(); //get current server time
$d2 = date_create("2020-02-01");//some future date
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);

echo $diff->days; //works fine & displays result perfectly
if($diff->days > 30) {echo "month of difference";} //error here
```

Comment: Works for me, so the error isn't there. https://3v4l.org/EZkMn

Comment: You should possibly take a look at the whole error, as it says where the error definitely oncurrs.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it is showing line number for error at the above mentioned line only

Comment: How about subtracting timestamps? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176609/calculate-total-seconds-in-php-dateinterval

Comment: Running your code on PHP7 produces the output `1083month of difference` for me without any errors. The cause of the issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this in order to convert into integer

```
$diffDays= intval($diff->format("%d"));
if($diffDays > 30) {echo "month of difference";} //error here probably
```

Comment: i doubt if parseInt() is present in PHP

Comment: It isn't, it's a javascript function.

Comment: I am talking about PHP here

Comment: Thanks for notice I fixed it.