# Covert time duration format "%h%m%s" to seconds

Tags: php

I've a table with the following time format *"1h1m1s"* (or *"1m1s"*). So the question is how to convert it to seconds only format? For example *1m1s = 61 (seconds)*.

Tried to select from database and replace with an arithmetical operators in PHP, but it doesn't work.

```
$options = get_table($table_name, $order);
for($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++){
    $duration = $options[$i]['duration'];

    $original = array("h", "m", "s");
    $change   = array('*3600+', '*60+', '*1');

    $string = str_replace($original, $change, $duration);
    echo $string;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *"1h1m1s"* format looks pretty compatible with PHP's `DateInterval` class. You could construct one and then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149337/283366) to calculate the seconds.

For example, you just need to uppercase the letters in *"1h1m1s"*, then prefix it with *"PT"* to make it an [*interval spec*](http://php.net/manual/dateinterval.construct.php#refsect1-dateinterval.construct-parameters).

```
/**
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149337/283366, please upvote it
 * @param DateInterval $dateInterval
 * @return int seconds
 */
function dateIntervalToSeconds($dateInterval)
{
    $reference = new DateTimeImmutable;
    $endTime = $reference->add($dateInterval);

    return $endTime->getTimestamp() - $reference->getTimestamp();
}

$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . strtoupper($duration));
$seconds = dateIntervalToSeconds($interval);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/UaEYB

Comment: @TimSadvak you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote the main part of this answer over here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149337/283366