# how to calculate the different between two datetime on seconds?

Tags: php, date, datetime, yii

i want to calculate different between two datetime in seconds and check if the result > 300sec

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2016-03-25 19:29:21");
$d2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: `$diff = $d2->getTimestamp() - $d1->getTimestamp();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get interval seconds between two datetime in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519228/get-interval-seconds-between-two-datetime-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

```
if($d2->format('U')-$d1->format('U')>300){
    // greater than 300
}else{
    // less than 300
}
```

Answer (score 4):

please check following code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2016-03-25 19:29:21');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %S seconds');
echo $elapsed;
```