# PHP switch: calculate dates

Tags: php, date, switch-statement

I made this switch, but I dont know this last step (the ?? and the comments).
If someone can help me, thanks a lot!

```
<?
   $nuDatumTijd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   $nuUur = date("H");
   switch(true)
   {
      case $nuUur > 8 && $nuUur < 13:
      $aantSecErbij = ??; // number of seconds untill the first next 13:00
      $weerOp = date($nuDatumTijd,$aantSecErbij);
      echo $weerOp;
      break;
      
      case $nuUur > 12 && $nuUur < 18:
      $aantSecErbij = ??; // number of seconds untill the first next 19:00
      $weerOp = date($nuDatumTijd,$aantSecErbij);
      echo $weerOp;
      break;
      
      case $nuUur > 17 && $nuUur < 22:
      $aantSecErbij = ??; // number of seconds untill the first next 9:00 (so that is the next day)
      $weerOp = date($nuDatumTijd,$aantSecErbij);
      echo $weerOp;
      break;
   }
?>
```

Comment: These are invalid switch case statements - use else if statements instead (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: This should slove the core issue for you: [date difference in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519228/get-interval-seconds-between-two-datetime-in-php/17114475).

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I can re-write it to else/if. But the question about $aantSecErbij stays.

Comment: This line $weerOp = date ($nuDatumTijd, $aantSecErbij); is nonsense. What do you expect for $weerOp. Please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have fixed it this way, thanks for your input:

```
$nuUur = date("H");

        if ($nuUur > 8 && $nuUur < 13)
        {
            $weerOp = strtotime('today 13:00');
            $weerOpNetjes = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $weerOp);
            echo $weerOpNetjes;
        }
        elseif ($nuUur > 12 && $nuUur < 18)
        {
            $weerOp = strtotime('today 19:00');
            $weerOpNetjes = date('H:i', $weerOp);
            echo $weerOpNetjes;
        }
        elseif ($nuUur > 17 && $nuUur < 22)
        {
            $weerOp = strtotime('tomorrow 9:00');
            $weerOpNetjes = date('H:i', $weerOp);
            echo $weerOpNetjes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

switch-case can be used this way too, no problem about that.

```
$aantSecErbij = ??; // number of seconds untill the first next 13:00
```

If this means the number of seconds until today's 1pm then the following will get you the timestamp of today's 1pm.

```
$now = getdate();
$time1pm = mktime(13, 0, 0, $now['mon'], $now['mday'], $now['year']);
```

If it means the number of seconds between now and today's 1pm then you need to subtract with current timestamp.

```
$now = getdate();
$diff1pm = mktime(13, 0, 0, $now['mon'], $now['mday'], $now['year']) - time();
```

.

```
$aantSecErbij = ??; // number of seconds untill the first next 9:00 (so that is the next day)
```

For the next day you can add 1 to the day part and don't have to worry about the end of month. PHP will figure out the right date for you.

```
$now = getdate();
$tomorrow9am = mktime(9, 0, 0, $now['mon'], $now['mday'] + 1, $now['year']);
```

Comment: by the way, what's your language? it's interesting.

Comment: Dutch, complicated for foreign people.

Comment: I haven't used your solution as you can see, but thank you very much for your time!

Comment: no problem, your use of strtotime is quite creative.